# How often should math students take day breaks and longer breaks or vacations? Any research?

Tags: soft-question, education, advice

John Edensor Littlewood wrote in page 197 of Littlewood's Miscellany

"For a week without teaching duties - and here I think I am preaching to the converted - I believe in on afternoon and the following day off."

"At one time I used to work 7 days week (apart, of course, from 3-week chunks of holidays). I experimented during the Long Vacation with a Sunday off, and presently began to notice that ideas had a way of coming on Mondays."

1. What's the optimal frequency at which math students take complete days off math? How many days off? By "break" I mean at least a whole day away from math, and not just a break every hour. Is there any research on this?
2. What's the optimal frequency at which math should be paused for long breaks/vacations? Is there any research on this?
3. Is there any research on the subject of breaks/rest periods for math students? I'm very interested to hear what other mathematicians have done as students.

Comment: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/on-time-management/

Comment: While certainly of interest to mathematicians and mathematics students, this is either off topic (the research you seek is *not* mathematical one, and in fact can be asked about any discipline; try a cognitive science website for that) or primarily opinion based (my experience may differ from other people's experience with taking breaks shorter and longer).

Comment: @JacquelynLi: Thanks for the bounty and sorry for misusing this comment section. I didn't see another way to send you a note. Regards, Markus

Answer (score 1):

as a High School student I find it helpful to take about one day off maths a week if it is advanced theory (complex number system) but for easier theories (cosin+sin+tangent...etc.), I take about 2-3 days off a week. There is bound to be research on this, but I think that if you take on board the proven fact of "canoeing upstream" then you might think that at the most only pause/take off 15 days for a vacation or 20 max for a holiday. (If you don't stay still or continue to canoe against the stream you will gradually decrease in skill) And for 3., I don't think I've earned the right to answer that, so hopefully you find the aboe block text useful! _Wangipapa

Comment: I got the suggestion to take a day of a week from studying at university, and not studying for an exam the day before (perhaps study other subjects, not for the exam; that only makes you nervous and tired, you won't learn anything significant anyway)